# Is it possible to generate formatting members in Visual Studio similar to Rider?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tostring, rider, jetbrains-rider

Is there a way to generate formatting members in Visual Studio like in Rider?
When I generate `ToString` in Visual studio I get this:

[image]

Which is useless to me.
when I generate formatting members in Rider I get this:

[image]

Which is far better.
Is there a way to generate the Second one automatically in Visual Studio as well?

(using Visual Studio 2022 Community Version BTW)

Comment: When you post a question here, post your code as text, formatted as `code`, never include a picture of your code like you did. I suspect the answer to your question is _No_

Comment: It's probably possible to achieve with ReSharper. Otherwise I'd just go for the manual approach which gives you full control over the string output.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible when using ReSharper in Visual Studio. As you can read [in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Generation__Formatting_Members.html), all your possibilities in Rider are also present in ReSharper.
This is due to the fact that Rider basically "only" runs ReSharper in the background to do all its magic. So typically everything that is possible in R# is also possible in Rider.